# Getting performance measurement tools from Linux on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, performance

Mac OS X doesn't seem to have the Linux performance tools perf, [pidstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/man_pidstat.html), or mpstat.

What other software has equal functionality on OS X? Or, how can I install these?

Comment: Can you add some details about what these tools do? There are tools on OS X as well but it might be easier to point you into the right direction if you add some details.

Comment: the wiki link [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux),pidstat http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/man_pidstat.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, I've edited the man page link into the question (you could actually do this yourself). Guessing from your comment below you are looking to solve a specific problem with the tools (e.g. profiling java code). You may get better answers if you edit the question into asking how to solve this in OS X than looking for 1:1 replacements of some Linux tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Instruments in XCode - not sure if it covers all of the functionality of the Linux tools you mention, but Instruments seems to be the preferred performance analyzer on Mac.

Comment: thanks ,could you simple tell how use instrumetns in Xcode